# passing objects to action methods in mvc places properties in querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am passing an object to an action method and that action method displays the view but it has all the proerties in the querystring and I do not want that (I have a long json string that cannot pass in url). How can I pass in a model object and not have it in the querystring? Also when you have a strong type view, Where does the object values for the Model store? Thanks for any help.

```
      //This works fine when I am calling /controller/uploader
        public ActionResult Uploader(Model model)
        {
        //logic
        return View(model);
        }

        //But when I am on another method and want to call uploader it does pass the object but puts //all the data in a querystring
        public void DoSomething(string val, string anotherval){
        Model model = new Model();
        Uploader(model);//This passes the object but when uploader page shows it has all the    //model object properties in querystring and I do not want that.

 return RedirectToAction("Uploader",model);//or this does the same thing
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the POST method on the html form:

```
<form action="/uploader" method="POST">
    <!-- maybe some input elements? -->
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This will transfer the data as Form Encoded within the request body and keep the data out of the query string.